# flutter problem: how to logout from apple sign in?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test, flutter-ios

### I am using "Sign_in _with_apple" plugin.
I did not understood how to logout from that.

I am using "Sign_in _with_apple" plugin.
I did not understood how to logout from that.

This is my functionality for apple signin.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple.dart';

/// Generates a cryptographically secure random nonce, to be included in a
/// credential request.
String generateNonce([int length = 32]) {
  final charset =
      '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-._';
  final random = Random.secure();
  return List.generate(length, (_) => charset[random.nextInt(charset.length)])
      .join();
}

/// Returns the sha256 hash of [input] in hex notation.
String sha256ofString(String input) {
  final bytes = utf8.encode(input);
  final digest = sha256.convert(bytes);
  return digest.toString();
}

 signInWithApple() async {
  // To prevent replay attacks with the credential returned from Apple, we
  // include a nonce in the credential request. When signing in with
  // Firebase, the nonce in the id token returned by Apple, is expected to
  // match the sha256 hash of `rawNonce`.
  final rawNonce = generateNonce();
  final nonce = sha256ofString(rawNonce);

  // Request credential for the currently signed in Apple account.
  final appleCredential = await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
    scopes: [
      AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
      AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName,
    ],
    nonce: nonce,
  );

  // Create an `OAuthCredential` from the credential returned by Apple.
  final oauthCredential = OAuthProvider("apple.com").credential(
    idToken: appleCredential.identityToken,
    rawNonce: rawNonce,
  );

  // Sign in the user with Firebase. If the nonce we generated earlier does
  // not match the nonce in `appleCredential.identityToken`, sign in will fail.
  final result = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(oauthCredential);
  // return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(oauthCredential);
   print(result.user!.displayName.toString());
   print(result.user!.email.toString());
   print(result.user!.uid.toString());
   print(result.additionalUserInfo!.username.toString());

}
```

I want logout functionality for this sign in fuctionality

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Auth has a function called signOut(), you can use it like this:

```
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
```

Comment: That would only log you out from FirebaseAuth. Incidently, gmail package has a signOut option built onto it. Does `FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut()` sign you out of apple login as well?

Comment: please I need this answer as well, does the 'FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut()' function sign you out from apple signin as well? because 'google_sign_in' has the 'GoogleSignIn().signOut()' command as well.